# How to make C++ debug statements appear in the gdb console

Tags: c++, gdb, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to debug an application in gdb running on Ubuntu 18.04.

In some parts of the code, I can set breakpoints and successfully debug problems.

But in other parts, triggering a breakpoint causes the process to exit.

Is there some way I can get debut statements to appear in the gdb console?

I currently use gdb to attach to the process and then debug from that point.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "debug statements." If you run the program from the console with GDB all standard output and standard error messages will print there. But if you run the program from an GUI application launcher and then attach to it the output and error will still be going to the GUI's standard output, some log file like `~/.xsession-errors` or the systemd journal which you can watch with `journalctl -ef`

Comment: Or if the debug statements are syslog calls the output will be in the system log. `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/syslog` or other file depending on your setup. Or again, in the systemd journal.

Comment: I have code (std::cout) that sends statements to standard out but they are not showing up in the gdb console.  But I know those functions are getting executed because when I set a breakpoint there, it breaks (but then the process dies as I mentioned in my original post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have code (std::cout) that sends statements to standard out but they are not showing up in the gdb console.

Nor should you expect them to.

When an application is started, its `std::cout` messages are going to file descriptor 1 (`stdout`). This can be the terminal window in which the app was started, or a file if the output was redirected. It could also be a pipe or `/dev/null`.

GDB does not "steal" that output (if it did, it would be harder to debug a program that is the source of input for another program going through a pipe).

Your first task should be to determine *where* the output is going. On Linux, this is usually as easy as `ls -l /proc/$pid/fds/1` (replace `$pid` with the actual process id of the process you are debugging).

An additional complication is that the `stdout` can be fully buffered (if it goes into a file, pipe or socket), and may not be `flush`ed by the time your breakpoint is hit.

P.S. In theory, you can "steal" the output from wherever it's going to your current terminal by running the following GDB commands:

```
(gdb) print open("/dev/tty", 2, 0)  # open new fd in the inferior process
                                    # going to current terminal.
                                    # This will print something, e.g. 5

# Now make stdout go to that newly-opened fd
(gdb) call dup2($whatever_last_command_printed, 1)
```

but I wouldn't recommend this, as it can interfere with the program in unexpected ways.